# Python 2.7 with Webpy - flup or modwsgi?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mod-wsgi, web.py, flup

I am unsure which of the two I should go for. Flup or modwsgi.

Flup seems to have very little documentation and even less people adding to the code. modwsgi on the other hand seems to be widely supported.

I just want to start running my webpy environmental so that I can utilize Python scripts online. But this thing stops me from moving ahead. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that `flup`'s author has discontinued development, but that's at best a rumor (someone please correct me!). I use `flup` in FastCGI mode on several Django sites, because it comes pre-integrated with Django, so it's an easy choice. I've never had a problem with it, beyond some oddities in the formatting of command line options.

I don't know much about mod_wsgi, as we switched from Apache to Nginx some time ago.

One downside of Flup/FastCGI is that you're managing your own server processes, whereas with mod_wsgi, Apache manages the processes for you.

web.py appears to have [a good cookbook section](http://webpy.org/cookbook/) with recipes for either solution. mod_wsgi looks like the simplest solution to me.

If you don't mind managing your processes (I don't), I understand there's been some excitement and momentum surrounding [Gunicorn](http://gunicorn.org/) and [uWSGI](http://projects.unbit.it/uwsgi/). These may be worth checking out. I've used Gunicorn with Django and Tornado web servers, and have no complaints about it.

Comment: uwsgi seems to be the flavor of the month; where as gunicorn is more easily integrated (especially with django)

Comment: I should say that I've used Gunicorn with both Django and Tornado, and found it really easy to use, mainly because the docs are good.

Comment: My only problem is that web.py is not packaged together with a simple Apache dependency like Django is with flup. 

Choice seems to stand with modwsgi then.

Comment: I often base these decisions on the quality of documentation and the simplicity of configuration. :) web.py appears to have example code for either option. mod_wsgi appears to be simpler. From my angle it's a toss-up, but modwsgi sounds like a solid choice, with fewer moving parts.

Comment: My thoughts exactly David! The less complexity in setting things up, the more focus on coding there can be. 

Would love to hear other web.py dev's what they use though. And what their setup is and has proven to work regardless of the challenges they faced.

Answer (score 0):

I use nginx and uwsgi to deploy my own web.py apps, seems faster and consumes less ram than apache+mod_wsgi, the setup is not as easy though. I have to run supervisord to ensure that all uwsgi processes are on.

Don't use flup, I think its considered to be a bit outdated way of deploying python web apps.